# Flag chat room for notification of new messages

Tags: feature-request

Moving extended conversations in comments into chat seems like a good idea. However, generally those types of chats are not real time. Additionally, users have to manually check the chat rooms to see if any new messages have been posted.

In order for chat rooms to have the same benefits of extended comment conversations (notifications), it would be ideal if a user could flag a chat room they are interested in. When a new message is posted to the flagged chat, the user would be notified in the standard manner with a red notification in the upper left. Perhaps this flagging could be automatic in the case of moving a comment conversation to chat.

Answer (score 1):

Would this really be beneficial with how busy some chat rooms are? Or are you always creating separate chats for these conversations?

I also feel like @UserName is sufficient. I can confirm that if you don't check the chatroom directly for these pings it does show up as a notification in your inbox. It happens to me plenty.